# GoogleFit Sample Not Working

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-fit

I am trying the BasicHistory Sample whis stores a data and then read it but in my case the code get stuck at the insert call.await call does not return anything i have tried using the asynchronous way also,here is the code

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status insertStatus =
Fitness.HistoryApi.insert(mClient, insertRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: What does your insertRequest look like?  And is mClient authorized and connected?

Answer (score 1):

Have you requested the right permissions?

According to that Google Fit sample, it only requires permission for "Activity". If you change the data type used in that sample for other different, make sure you are setting right permissions. Read authorization section in [Google Fit Doc](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/authorization) for more information.

You can add several permissions just adding a new scope to client:

```
    // Create the Google API Client
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE))
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert a DataType into google fit you must create a DataSet of the same type and make sure you built GoogleApiClient with appropriate Scopes Like jose said above. Below is the example of inserting Height in google fit

```
public boolean saveUserHeight(int heightCentimiters) {
    // to post data
    float height = ((float) heightCentimiters) / 100.0f;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    DataSet heightDataSet = createDataForRequest(DataType.TYPE_HEIGHT, // for
            DataSource.TYPE_RAW, height, // weight in kgs
            startTime, // start time
            endTime, // end time
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS // Time Unit, for example,
                                    // TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
    );
    com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status heightInsertStatus = Fitness.HistoryApi
            .insertData(fitnessClient, heightDataSet).await(1,
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    if (heightInsertStatus.isSuccess()) {
        //Log.e("Height", heightCentimiters+"Inserted");
    } else {
        //Log.e("Height", "inserted failed");
    }
    return heightInsertStatus.isSuccess();
}
```