# Add/Read weight and height in GoogleFit? Android

Tags: android, google-fit

By Google, I got this code to insert `DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA`. but how to insert `TYPE_HEIGHT AND TYPE_WEIGHT` using Android

```
 com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status insertStatus =
                    Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mClient, dataSet)
                            .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Answer (score 6):

To insert data, you need to create a new DataSet object for both height and weight.

I have created a method in order to get a DataSet object with the necessary parameters for a request.

```
/**
 * This method creates a dataset object to be able to insert data in google fit
 * @param dataType DataType Fitness Data Type object
 * @param dataSourceType int Data Source Id. For example, DataSource.TYPE_RAW
 * @param values Object Values for the fitness data. They must be int or float
 * @param startTime long Time when the fitness activity started
 * @param endTime long Time when the fitness activity finished
 * @param timeUnit TimeUnit Time unit in which period is expressed
 * @return
 */
private DataSet createDataForRequest(DataType dataType, int dataSourceType, Object values,
                                     long startTime, long endTime, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName(mAppId)
            .setDataType(dataType)
            .setType(dataSourceType)
            .build();

    DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);
    DataPoint dataPoint = dataSet.createDataPoint().setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, timeUnit);

    if (values instanceof Integer) {
        dataPoint = dataPoint.setIntValues((Integer)values);
    } else {
        dataPoint = dataPoint.setFloatValues((Float)values);
    }

    dataSet.add(dataPoint);

    return dataSet;
}
```

Then, you need to do something like this:

```
     DataSet weightDataSet = createDataForRequest(
           DataType.TYPE_WEIGHT,    // for height, it would be DataType.TYPE_HEIGHT
           DataSource.TYPE_RAW,
           value,                  // weight in kgs
           startTime,              // start time
           endTime,                // end time
           timeUnit                // Time Unit, for example, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
      );

    com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status weightInsertStatus =
            Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mClient, weightDataSet )
                    .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

It is very helpful if you read [Google Fit doc](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/). There, you can read more information about [data types](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types)

I hope this helps ^^

Comment: I did the same you suggest by following method : Please see my post: any idea why i'm getting : There was a problem inserting the dataset.

Comment: Try now, there was a typo in the doc.

Comment: By the way, have you requested permissions for writing in Google Fit API?

Comment: maybe you didn't add body permissions in your code. I recommend to read this response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390192/googlefit-sample-not-working/26959071#26959071

Comment: For me works only dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_WEIGHT).setFloat((Integer)values);

Comment: Are you working ok? i am showing errro: Application needs OAuth consent from the user. why? can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following method to insert Weight and Height in updated GoogleFit API:

```
private void insertWeightHeight(Context context, DataType dataType, float value) {
        long startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        long endTime = startTime;
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
                .setAppPackageName(getContext())
                .setDataType(dataType)
                .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
                .build();

        DataPoint dataPoint = DataPoint.builder(dataSource)
                .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .setFloatValues(value)
                .build();

        DataSet dataSet = DataSet.builder(dataSource)
                .add(dataPoint)
                .build();

        Fitness.getHistoryClient(context, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context))
                .insertData(dataSet)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        System.out.println("success");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("failed");
                    }
                });
    }
```

You can call this method as follow:

```
insertWeightHeight(getContext(), DataType.TYPE_WEIGHT, 70f);//weight in kg
insertWeightHeight(getContext(), DataType.TYPE_HEIGHT, 1.75f);//height in meter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private DataSet createDataForRequest(DataType dataType
,float dataSourceType
,int values
,long startTime, long endTime, TimeUnit timeUnit) {

    DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName(this)
            .setDataType(dataType)
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build();

    DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);
    DataPoint dataPoint = dataSet.createDataPoint().setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, timeUnit);

    float weight = Float.parseFloat(""+values);

    dataPoint = dataPoint.setFloatValues(weight);

    dataSet.add(dataPoint);

    return dataSet;
}

// to post data
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date now = new Date();
cal.setTime(now);
long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

DataSet weightDataSet = createDataForRequest(
        DataType.TYPE_WEIGHT,    // for height, it would be DataType.TYPE_HEIGHT
        DataSource.TYPE_RAW,
        56,                  // weight in kgs
        startTime,              // start time
        endTime,                // end time
        TimeUnit.MINUTES                // Time Unit, for example, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
);

com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status weightInsertStatus =
        Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mClient, weightDataSet )
                .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

// Before querying the data, check to see if the insertion succeeded.
if (!weightInsertStatus.isSuccess()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem inserting the dataset.");
    return null;
}

// At this point, the data has been inserted and can be read.
Log.i(TAG, "Data insert was successful!");

// I'm getting : There was a problem inserting the dataset.
```